# Create 3D effect of 2D line plot matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Question, I have a line data. However I wanted to be plotted with a 3D effect, which you can also choose as an option, for instance, within Office Excel/Powerpoint.

Currently I have the code below which kind of mimmics the effect (simply putting a lot of plots after each other):

Excel:

[image]

Matlab:

[image]

Matlab code:

```
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1, 10);
z = rand(1, 10);

figure; 
hold on;
for i = 1:20
   hFill = fill3(i*0.01*ones(1, 12), x([1 1:end end]), [0 y 0], 'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
   hFill = fill3((i*0.01*(ones(1, 12)))+2, x([1 1:end end]), [0 z 0], 'g', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
end

grid on;
xlim([0 10]);
view(3);
```

Comment: The solution is not workable in my opinion. And it is not for real data display, but to explain something.

Comment: What is wrong with the current solution? I guess better choice of axis limits, and perhaps normals and lighting may improve it visually

Comment: I feel like you're also missing a trick. `fill3` is specifically for filling a 3D polygon, but you're using it to fill a 2D polygon in 3D space. You could duplicate the `y`/`z` points, and have two planes of `x` points, then just fill one fat shape instead of 20 thin ones.

Comment: @Wolfie: It's not impractical. It's very useful to obfuscate your results!

Answer (score 2):

You could probably construct a closed surface in one single graphic object to represent your 3D curve, however I don't have time to work that out completely so I'll go the lazy way:
Instead of stacking multiple `fill` objects to give a 3d feeling, I build each curve with 3 objects:

- A top surface, with the desired `thickness`
- 2 patch objects to close the sides

Here goes:

```
%% Sample data
rng(12)
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1, 10) + .5 ;
z = rand(1, 10) + .5 ;

%% Parameters
alphaTop  = .5 ; % alpha value of the top of the surface
alphaSide = .5 ; % alpha value of the sides
thickness = .5 ; % thickness of each curve
separation = 1 ;  % separation of each curve
colors = {'b';'r'} ; % color for each curve

%% prepare patch coordinates
xp = x([1 1:end end 1]) ;
yp1 = [0 y 0 0] ;
yp2 = [0 z 0 0] ;
zp1 = zeros(size(yp1)) ;
zp2 = zeros(size(yp2)) + 1 ;

%% Prepare surface coordinates
xs  = [ xp; xp] ;
ys1 = [yp1;yp1] ;
ys2 = [yp2;yp2] ;
zs1 = zeros(size(xs)) ;
zs1(2,:) = zs1(2,:) + thickness ;
zs2 = zs1 + separation ;

%% Display
figure
hold on
% plot the sides (one patch on each side of each curve)
hp11 = patch(zp1          ,xp,yp1, colors{1} , 'FaceAlpha', alphaSide) ;
hp12 = patch(zp1+thickness,xp,yp1, colors{1} , 'FaceAlpha', alphaSide) ;

hp21 = patch(zp2          ,xp,yp2, colors{2} , 'FaceAlpha', alphaSide) ;
hp22 = patch(zp2+thickness,xp,yp2, colors{2} , 'FaceAlpha', alphaSide) ;

% plot the top surfaces
hs1 = surf(zs1,xs,ys1, 'FaceColor',colors{1},'FaceAlpha',alphaTop) ;
hs2 = surf(zs2,xs,ys2, 'FaceColor',colors{2},'FaceAlpha',alphaTop) ;

% refine plot
xlim([0 10]);ylim([0 10]); view(3);
xlabel('X') ; ylabel('Y') ; zlabel('Z') ;
```

Which yields:

[image: 3d curves]

Once this is built, you can regroup the graphic handles to group common properties assignments. For example:

```
%% Optional (modify common properties in group)
% regroup graphic handles for easy common property assignment
hg1 = [hp11;hp12;hs1] ;
hg2 = [hp21;hp22;hs2] ;
% set properties in group
set(hg1,'EdgeColor',colors{1},'FaceAlpha',0.2) ;
set(hg2,'EdgeColor',colors{2},'FaceAlpha',0.2) ;
```

To give your curves a nice transparent *mesh* style:
[image]

Ultimately, if you plan to apply this method to many curves, you should either package it in a function, or at least build your curves with a loop. It should be easy to convert as long as the parameters for each curve are in an array you can index into (like I did for the colors).